# Display certain text before executing ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't succeed with outputting this text before executing ajax. I know it has something to do with async/await, but after reading other posts and articles I still can't figure it out. Anyone able to help me with providing an updated code?

**This is the output (Calculating now...) I want before execution:**

```
$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td span.google').text('Calculating now...');
```

**Full code:**

```
$(function(){
        $('.calculate').click(function(){
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td span.google').text('Calculating now...');
            
            var total_distance = 0;
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td span.tripleg').each(function() {
                var origin = $(this).attr('origin');
                var destinations = $(this).attr('destinations');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'includes/calculate_distance.php?action=distance_analysis',
                    data: {"origin": origin, "destinations": destinations, "google_api_key": google_api_key},
                    async: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        total_distance = total_distance + parseFloat(result);
                    }
                });
            });

            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td span.google').text(total_distance.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your issue is that your code does this:  1) set text, 2) set text, 3) run ajax.   It *is* setting your text, but you don't have time to see it.  Comment out the `.text(total_distance.toFixed(2));` and you'll see it fine (*assuming* selectors are correct ofc),   Move `.text(total_distance.toFixed(2));` inside the `success:` callback.

Comment: That is correct, but when I move it to the success callback, the text Calculating now... doesn't change to the actual result

Comment: Does your `success:` callback fire?  If yes (assuming yes) then the problem is that you've moved it *as-is*, including the `this`.  But `this` means something different in the `success:`.   Make a copy(variable) of `this` outside the ajax, eg `$('.calculate').click(function(){ $this = $(this); ..` then in `success:` use `$this.parent("td")....`  (or better, just store the span.google and use that).

Comment: Ow indeed, fair point! I have amended that now and that seems to work. But unfortunately, the text doesn't change to 'Calculating now...' first. It fills in directly the result.

Comment: I still have a feeling that the code before the ajax call only gets executed as soon as the ajax is done.

Comment: I removed the `async: false,` part and now it works as it should :)

Comment: Yes, my bad, didn't notice `aysnc:false` as it's deprecated (see all the warnings you get in your browser console), so your original code did this:  1) set text, 2) wait for ajax, 3) set text, 4) *update UI*.   As async:false is UI blocking, the UI doesn't get updated until your js function/event handler completes.